# how to get all data from table2 with sender and receiver name which linked with id from user(table1) table

Tags: mysql

i want to display all data .. bt sender and receiver's name are stored in user table. They are linked on message table with their user id. Now i need both of there name for single row.

```
public function all_transferData()
{
    $this->db->select('t.filename, t.message_subject, users.username, users.email');
    $this->db->from('transfer_history as t');
    $this->db->join('users', 't.sender_id = users.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: is the receiver_id stored in the transfer_history table?

Comment: You mentioned table `message`, but youd didn't let us know how table message is linked to tables history and users. Please share a database-digagram (aka ERM-diagram) so we can see how all these tables are linked together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `user` table twice, once to query the sender data and another one to query the receiver data.
If the `receiver_id` is stored in the `transfer_history` table, you can try something like the following:

```
    public function all_transferData()
    {
      $this->db->select('t.filename, t.message_subject, 
        su.username as sender_name, su.email as sender_email, 
        ru.username as receiver_name, ru.email as receiver_email');
      $this->db->from('transfer_history as t');
      $this->db->join('users as su', 't.sender_id = su.user_id');
      $this->db->join('users as ru', 't.receiver_id = ru.user_id');
      $query = $this->db->get();

      return $query->result();
    }
```